# Unable to get td column value on click

Tags: jquery

how can i get the specific column(status) value by click on get

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">get</a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td grid-colid='Status'>false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">get</a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td grid-colid='Status'>true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">get</a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td grid-colid='Status'>false</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

```
var statusVal = $(this).closest('tr').next("td[grid-colid='Status']").html();
```

Comment: what is `$(this)` here..?

Comment: @ Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy I need specific row's column value by clicking on get

Comment: Try,

    `var statusVal = $(this).closest('tr').find("td[grid-colid='Status']").html();`

Comment: Down voting to those kind of question which show what he had done to get the right answer are bad practices. (eg. var statusVal = $(this).closest('tr').next("td[grid-colid='Status']").html();)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `.find()`

```
$('table a').on('click',function(){
    var statsVal=$(this).closest('tr').find('td[grid-colid="Status"]').html()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML is not going to change you can simply transverse to the right elements without having to use any CSS selector which would be faster.

```
$(".button").on("click", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();    
    // first parent give the td, the second give the tr
    var status = $(this).parent().parent().children().last().text();

    console.log(status);
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5VEeE/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use find() method as @Anton, but also you can do this by using nextAll() method too (and it's good too to select multiple elements):

```
var statusVal = $(this).closest('td').nextAll("td[grid-colid='Status']").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

For a matter of performance it's better if you use event delegation (set a single handler instead of setting an handler for each link) and retrieve the right column with `find()`. With the given example it is not strictly necessary to also specify the attribute value in the selector.

Furthermore, if you need to retrieve plain text, then just use `text()` method instead of `html()`;

```
$('table').on('click', 'a', function() {
   var statusVal = $(this).closest('tr').find("td[grid-colid]").text();
   console.log(statusVal);
});
```

**Example**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LskuG